# How to download the updated version of a server file in IE (PHP)?

Tags: php, internet-explorer, caching, csv, download

Internet Explorer is giving me a serious headache...

What I want to do is - create a button upon clicking which an .csv file is getting downloaded to a client. This .csv file includes information stored in one of the result tables I am producing on the page.

Before I create this button I am calling an internal function to create the .csv file based on the currently displayed table. I create this .csv file on the server. I'll inlcude this function here just in case, but I don't think it is of any help. Like I said I create this file, before I am creating the button.

```
/*
/ Creates a .csv file including all the data stored in $records
/   @table_headers  - array storing the table headers corresponding to $records
/   @records        - two dimensional array storing the records that will be written into the .csv file
/   @filename       - string storing the name of the .csv file created by this from
*/
public function export_table_csv( $table_headers, $records, $filename )
{       
    // Open the $filename and store the handle to it in $csv_file
    $csv_file = fopen( "temp/" . $filename, "w" );

    // Write the $table_headers into $csv_file as a first row
    fputcsv( $csv_file, $table_headers );       
    // Iterate through $records and write each record as one line separated with commas to $csv_file
    foreach ( $records as $row )
        fputcsv( $csv_file, $row );

    // Close $csv_file 
    fclose( $csv_file );
} // end export_table_csv()
```

I have that working fine. I got the 'Export' button and I am using its onClick() event where I am using a one-liner:

```
window.open( 'temp/' . $export_filename );
```

Now, it works as intended in all browsers, except IE. The file still gets downloaded, but then when I perform some filtering on the table I am displaying on the page (the page gets reloaded whenever new filters are applied), and then press the 'Export' button again, it somehow downloads an old version of the .csv file with the old filters applied, not the current ones, even though this .csv file is re-written every time the new filters are being applied and the page gets reloaded.

It is as if the .csv file I am exporting is stored in IE's cache or something... It is really annoying as the export works fine in all other browsers... Chrome and FF always download the latest version of the file from the server, IE updates the file randomly, sometimes only after I submit the page with different filters a few times...

I didn't include too many lines of my code as I rather think I am simply missing some kind of meta tag or something from my code, rather than have a logical bug in the lines I have already written.

I am really confused by this and annoyed to say the least... I really start to dislike IE now...

I appreciate any suggestions on this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a 'cache buster' to prevent IE from caching the resource.

If you add a GET parameter (with a value that changes every time you load the page) to the URL, IE (or rather: any browser) will think it's a different file to get, so do something like this:

```
window.open( 'temp/" . $export_filename . "?cachebuster=" . uniqid(true) . "' );
```

If the value needs to change every time you click (not on page load):

```
window.open( 'temp/" . $export_filename . "?cachebuster="' + Math.random() );
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked like a charm. +3